# Incorrect tag added on purpose (?) by the same user to many questions

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

A user added a tag with a spelling mistake to most of questions tagged with [android-4.4](/questions/tagged/android-4.4). The incorrect tag is [anndroid-4.4](/questions/tagged/anndroid-4.4) with double n.

An example here https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19724058/revisions

I can retag all the questions (there's not many of them) but can something be done about it? For me, that's an abuse of the tag system. Can the incorrect tag be removed?

The user is https://stackoverflow.com/users/1029088/bishan

Comment: Good catch. This *could* be a mistake / misunderstanding how the UI works though

Comment: But why would he bother to make a tag wiki for it though?

Comment: I thought so too initially but then the same incorrect tag was added to question along with a correct one by the same user.

Comment: @probablyPekka a 2K user who has been a member for over a year... seems odd to be adding a tag to a question with the tag he "accidentally" misspelled when they have the correct one.  Smells like an attempt at Taxidermist

Comment: I wrote a relevant communication to the user.  Now that the tag is gone from all questions, it will age away overnight.

Comment: @RobertHarvey A synonym has also been created for this incorrect tag (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203882/synonym-request-kitkat-android-4-4). Can that be moved too?

Comment: Sorry for my part in this confusion - I goofed the synonym.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This wasn't that particular user's fault; a moderator (who has already been mocked) inadvertently created the synonym between kitkat and anndroid-4.4. He later went back and created the *proper* synonym, thus resolving the problem.

The editor you observed was merely trying to add the [kitkat](/questions/tagged/kitkat) tag to various questions (which was also unnecessary); As Robert noted, he's been informed of the synonym now.

Comment: Eh, sometimes things get really complicated and hard to track down...